# What's the diference between Quick Assist, Remote Assist, RemoteApp and Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-assistance

Microsoft offers 4 different ways for the user to share their screen in order to receive technical support from someone more knowledgable. Yes four. So what's the difference between them? I'm using Windows 10 20H2

[image: remote assistance]

[image: remote dekstop]

[image: remoteapp]

[image: quick assist]

Comment: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/whats-different-between-remote-desktop-connection-windows-remote-assistance/

Comment: and>>>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Assist

Comment: Not sure why this was closed, the question is pretty clear.

Comment: I've updated my question now to provide screenshots. Can you reopen my question now?

Comment: Yes but I'm asking for the differences between 4 similar software, not just 2 as the links you gave me show.

Comment: There is only information on each software, no explanation anywhere on the differences on all 4, you need to research all 4 and conclude the differences for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - **Remote Desktop** - allows you to connect to another computer. This    isn't really intended for use in troubleshooting, and doesn't
>   allow    two people to see the same screen at the same time. It lets
>   you use    another computer as if you were sitting in front of it.
> - **Remote App** - similar to Remote Desktop, but is intended for companies to allow their workers to connect to their workplace
>   computers and can be used to remotely use an entire desktop, or only
>   remotely use one specific app at a time.
> - **Quick Assist** - a way to get or provide help, allows two people to work on the same computer at the same time.
> - **Remote Assistance** - the old version of Quick Assist, first built in Windows Me/Windows XP decades ago, it's only still included
>   for    people that still need to support such old systems. Quick
>   Assist is    the new / modern way of accomplishing the same task.
>
> Shawn "Cmdr" Keene | Microsoft MVP - Windows Insider | CmdrKeene.com |
> tweet: @CmdrKeene

[Here is the source web page.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-winapps-appscat_productivity/whats-the-diference-between-quick-assist-remote/4b4795eb-6126-4db7-8503-c02ad925df70)